# Is there a way to find first component of type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so basically I have a script which highlights gameobjects with a specific tag if your mouse is pointing at.
After it's highlighted you need to press a specific key and you will execute a public function inside the interactable object. Now the problem is when I want to search a specific component instead of using it's name, any help is expected. :)

Comment: Please provide an example with minimal code for desired output and what is currently happening for a reproducible example.

Comment: What's an _interactable object_? What does _I want to search a specific component instead of using it's name_ mean?

Comment: If you can set and clear highlighting on objects, then set and clear an "isSelected" bit, too. Have ALL the game objects listen to the key press events but only the one that isSelected should respond.

Comment: @Flydog57 I want to search a script in a gameobject, but the only way I can do is with GetComponent<Name>(); and I want to do something like GetComponent<typeof(Script)>();

Comment: @Chuck I know but actually I need to make a lot of interactable objects and this is the easiest and correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Script isn't a type, but `Component` is the base type for anything that can be attached to a game object (hence `GetComponent` having the name it does). Components include things like `Transform`, `MeshFilter`, etc. Most scripts that you'll write inherit `MonoBehaviour`, so you totally could do something like `GetComponent<MonoBehaviour>()` but then you'll get the one (or all, if you use GetComponents) of the `MonoBehaviour` scripts attached to the game object.

Since you're just blindly getting any script without knowing its type in advance, you're going to wind up with some big if/else chain where you keep trying to downcast the object to a concrete type that you can actually do something with.

The solution is to use an **interface**. If multiple classes can all do the same thing, then make an interface that encapsulates that functionality. In your case you might have an `IUseKeystrokes` interface for all the kinds of classes you could make that would use your keystroke sequence technique.

```
public interface IUseKeystrokes
{
    void Use(char keystroke);
}
```

Then you add that to any class you're writing and you'll get a compile error if you don't implement the `Use(char)` method.

```
public class MyThing : MonoBehaviour, IUseKeystrokes
{
    public void Use(char keystroke);
    // and other stuff for the class
}
```

and now finally you can call

```
IUseKeystrokes useKeystrokes = targetGameObject.GetComponent<IUseKeystrokes>();
```

and now it actually doesn't matter what class it is, no need to downcast, you just call

```
useKeystrokes.Use(keystroke);
```

Comment: Hello, I'd make a new post where I got the solution, do you know how to run a public void? I already have the found script but it's giving me error CS1061 when I do this: `FoundScript.FunctionName();`.

Comment: @Wonds are you sure it's public? That's usually the cause - it defaults to private if you don't explicitly give it public or protected. Otherwise I'd need to see the script for the class and the snippet that is trying to call the function.

Comment: Of course, I'd run it before with it's full name.

Comment: I'm actually dizzy so if you guys can check this post out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72524416/how-can-i-run-this-method