# How can I run this method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this public function which I don't know how to run (Last line).

````
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, distancia, mask))
        {
            Deselect();
            SelectedObject(hit.transform);
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Objeto Interactivo")
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    print(hit.collider);
                    print(hit.collider.transform);
                    if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out MonoBehaviour FoundScript))
                    {
                        Debug.Log(FoundScript.GetType().GetMethod("Interact")); // How to run this method?```
````

Comment: 100% working https://answers.unity.com/questions/376676/accessing-a-script-without-knowing-its-name.html

Comment: hang on lol I've got a long answer coming in

Comment: The last thing you want to do in any sort of game programming is use _.NET Reflection._  Rethink your design

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to explain in [my other, related answer (where I also mention to use an `interface`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507081/5171120), what you're doing here is getting **any** `MonoBehaviour` and then you're trying to downcast that script to a specific type.

What you're doing here is worse even, because you're not actually even downcasting, you're trying to use reflection to get a specific function by name.

You have a function, and clearly you know the function name - `Interact()`. How do you know this function exists? You must know *something* about what you're expecting to get here, otherwise you wouldn't be trying to use that `Interact()` method.

The problem with your code right now is that you're trying to call `GetMethod()`, which is returning information about the method. It's not actually giving you method, just basically metadata about the method.

If you want to actually invoke the method, if you want to call `FoundScript.Interact()`, then you need to somehow convert `FoundScript` from a generic `MonoBehaviour` to the actual class that has the `Interact()` method.

Somewhere, in some script, you've defined `Interact()` to be a `public void`. You haven't provided that code here, so let's assume that you've done it in some class that's called `MyInteractingObject`. You might have a class that looks like:

```
public class MyInteractingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Interact()
    {
        Debug.Log("This is an interaction.");
    }
}
```

Now what you need to do is to convert `FoundScript` from `MonoBehaviour` to a `MyInteractingObject`. You can try to do that from your code by creating a variable of type `MyInteractingObject`, but you'll get an error because a `FoundScript` is not *necessarily* a `MyInteractingObject`.

```
MyInteractingObject interactingObject = FoundScript; // Compile error
```

What you need to do to force that conversion is to ["cast"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) the FoundScript. This means you are going to try to treat `FoundScript` **as if** it were a `MyInteractingObject`.

```
MyInteractingObject interactingObject = (MyInteractingObject)FoundScript; // Will compile, but interactingObject will be null if the cast fails.
```

If you're allowed to treat it that way then you'll get `interactingObject` as a thing you can use. If you're not allowed to treat it that way (because `FoundObject` isn't actually a `MyInteractingObject`) then it will be `null` and you can't use it.

This means that, after you do the cast operation, you need to check to see if it's null. Picking up your code after you check the key:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
{
    print(hit.collider);
    print(hit.collider.transform);
    if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out MonoBehaviour FoundScript))
    {
        MyInteractingObject interactingObject = (MyInteractingObject)FoundScript;
        if(interactingObject != null)
        {
            interactingObject.Interact();
        }
    }
}
```

So here after you get your `FoundScript` off the `hit.collider` you try to cast it to `MyInteractingObject`. You would replace this name with whatever name you've got for your class.

Now, what you could do is to skip the cast step and just look for the `MyInteractingObject` instead of looking for `MonoBehaviour` and then trying to cast. Consider this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
{
    print(hit.collider);
    print(hit.collider.transform);
    if (hit.collider.TryGetComponent(out MyInteractingObject FoundScript))
    {
        interactingObject.Interact();
    }
}
```

Now if there isn't a `MyInteractingObject` attached to the `hit.collider` then the contents of that `if` statement never fire.

There are other ways you could optimize but I think it's probably best to try to exercise the fundamentals here. Good luck! :)

Comment: +1.  Considering OP is looking for a particular method or _contract_ on an object, consider encouraging the OP to use `interface`s rather than casting to a whole class if the latter isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: @MickyD that's exactly what I did in [my answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507081/5171120).

Comment: Ah sorry thanks for pointing that out.  +1 on that one too :)